# Erro requisição Ajax Jquery C#

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, webforms

Estou obtendo o erro 401 em uma consulta simples de Ajax com Jquery. Requisição:

```
    $().ready(function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: "Ajax/RetornoAjax.aspx/ObterResultados",
            type: "GET", //Caso não passe nenhum dado
            dataType: "json", //Informa que está esperando receber um json
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8", //Headers da pagina que é feita a requisição
            async: true, //Informando que a requisição será feita de forma nao sincronizada com a execução dos outros scripts - como em segundo plano. De certa forma faz com que seu success só execute após a requisição ser totalmente processada
            success: function (result, status, request) {
                console.log(result[0]);

                //Note que o result geralmente exibe ou como Object ou Document dependendo do retorno. Não tenho certeza devido a ser json - que não sou muito familiarizado
                alert("Estado atual---\n" + status + "\nResultado: " + result);
                //Abaixo está listando os header do conteudo que você requisitou, só para confirmar se você setou os header e dataType corretos
                alert("Informações da requisição: \n" + request.getAllResponseHeaders());
                confirmationValue = result; //Repassa o retorno da requisição para teste futuro
            },
            error: function (request, status, erro) {
                alert("Problema ocorrido: " + status + "\nDescição: " + erro);
                //Abaixo está listando os header do conteudo que você requisitou, só para confirmar se você setou os header e dataType corretos
                alert("Informações da requisição: \n" + request.getAllResponseHeaders());
            },
            complete: function (jqXHR, textStatus) {
                alert("Chegou ao fim: : " + textStatus);
                //Exibindo o valor que você obeteve e repassou para o confirmationValue
                //Exibindo o valor que você obeteve e repassou para o confirmationValue
                alert("Confirmation value: " + confirmationValue);
            }
        });

    })
```

Web Method:

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Web;
    using System.Web.UI;
    using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
    using System.Web.Services;
    using System.Data;
    using System.Web.Script.Serialization;

    namespace GestHos.PlanejamentosEstrategico.Indicador
    {
        public partial class RetornoAjax : System.Web.UI.Page
        {
            protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {

            }

            [WebMethod()]
            public static string ObterResultados()
            {
                JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();

                string Json = js.Serialize("Sim");

                return Json;
            }

        }
    }
```

Erro:

[image: Retorno da Requisição]

Como resolver este problema?

Answer (score 1):

> Erro HTTP 401 - não autorizado: Acesso negado devido a credenciais inválidas.

Teoricamente você não tem permissão para fazer a requisição. Abra o console do navegador e verifique se não está falando algo relacionado à "Same origin Policy" caso sim, será necessário configurar permissão no servidor para essa URL.

Para saber mais:

HTTP STATUS:  https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/HTTP/Status
SAME ORIGIN POLICY: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy

Comment: No console não tem nada falando de "Same origin Policy".

Comment: É exibido algum erro?

Comment: Aparece apenas "undefined" no console

Comment: bom então ai é problema na hora de exibir os dados na tela, no success, da um `console.log(result);` e dê uma olhada no que retorna.

Comment: Retorna: Object
ExceptionType
:
""
Message
:
"There was an error processing the request."
StackTrace
:
""
__proto__
:
Object

Comment: Como pode ver: ocorreu  o erro durante o processo da requisição, de uma olhada nesse link aonde contém o mesmo problema que você está tendo https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/pt-BR/78852569-ecad-4faf-abfa-f9209e2766e5/http-500-cors-erro-interno-do-servidor-no-iis6-server-com-jquery-aspnet-e-webservice?forum=aspnetpt há também esse outro que acredito eu, irá acaabr com seu problema : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16085834/handling-errors-raised-by-jquery-ajax-method

Comment: Eu até tentei implementar algumas coisas desse link, mas não funcionou. Estou achando que pode ser alguma segurança de servidor, pois estou desenvolvendo remotamente em um servidor (Server 2008)

Comment: Como eu disse, está barrando por conta de permissão, pesquise mais sobre Cross Origin policy que com certeza esse é o problema. Deixo aqui mais um link para ajudar: https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/HTTP/Controle_Acesso_CORS  Boa sorte!

Comment: Beleza, valeu! Vou estudar mais sobre o assunto.

Comment: Por nada! Se a resposta lhe foi útil, não esqueça de classificar! :) Abraços!